# Batch file for Windows - problem with goto

Tags: windows, batch-file, goto

I'm writing a Windows batch file which starts an executable file depending on the status of the wifi connection, and a user choice.

The script uses an infinite loop with a `for`.

```bash
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
timeout /t 300
for /l %%n in (1,0,10) do (
    netsh wlan connect ssid="xxxx" name="xxxx"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo error
    )
    choice /c sna /d n /t 30 /m "Text"
    if errorlevel 3 (
        echo Choice A
        exit
    ) else if errorlevel 2 (
        echo choiche N
    ) else if errorlevel 1 (
        echo choiche S
    ) else if errorlevel 0 (
        echo Default
        exit
    )
)
```

After the first `if`, that checks the connection is established, I would like to insert a `goto` to skip the `choice` part and go directly to the end of the loop and restart the iteration.

I tried to put a simple `goto end` and label `:end` but the batch doesn't work properly.

```bash
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
timeout /t 300
for /l %%n in (1,0,10) do (
    netsh wlan connect ssid="xxxx" name="xxxx"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo error
        goto end   <<<<-----------------------
    )
    choice /c sna /d n /t 30 /m "Text"
    if errorlevel 3 (
        echo Choice A
        exit
    ) else if errorlevel 2 (
        echo choiche N
    ) else if errorlevel 1 (
        echo choiche S
    ) else if errorlevel 0 (
        echo Default
        exit
    )
    :end
)
```

I don't know if it's a matter of environment variables or something else.

Comment: Also, no labels within code blocks (your second code) are allowed and every `goto` breaks *all* loops (not just the inner block, you want to break, but back to "top level").

Comment: Switch to `if !errorlevel! equ 3 (...)`, `if !errorlevel! equ 2 (...)`, etc. (no `else` needed with this syntax)

Comment: @Stephan Maybe I could youse the call command to another batch file that could do the check on connection and return an errorlevel? Is it possible?

Comment: yes, you could call another batch file, but you can also just call a label ("subroutine") within the same script. (see `call /?` for how to pass parameters). You can use `exit /b 5` to return an errorlevel of `5` to the main code (or calling script).

Comment: @Stephan: The `if (...) else if (...) else if (...) ...` is a valid and clear syntax that replaces the `switch/case` command/instruction in other languages... Every `if` have just one `else`

Comment: @Aacini: you're right. Got confused by the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using conditionals, e.g. `&& (echo success) || echo fail`, for the first command. This has the effect of reversing your initial `if`/`else` structure, and thus removes the need for a `goto`.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 300
For /L %%G In (1,0,10) Do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Connect SSID="xxxx" Name="xxxx" && (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C sna /D n /T 30 /M "Text"
        If ErrorLevel 3 (
            Echo Choice A
        )
        If Errorlevel 2 (
            Echo Choice N
        )
        If ErrorLevel 1 (
            Echo Choice S
        )
    ) || (
        Echo Error
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work properly. Now I have to deal with the fact that netsh wlan connect return no error even if the ssid is not reachable but present as known network.

Comment: Do you mean ```SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Connect SSID="xxxx" Name="xxxx" 2>NUL && (```? or are you suggesting that the command you are using and I have replicated in my answer does not do what you hoped it would? If the latter, then that is another question, and my answer above has solved your issue.

Comment: It's a already known problem of the command netsh wlan connect. Testing the solutions seems to return errorlevel 0 even if the connection to a specific SSID doesen't go well. Finally I used this workaround:
netsh wlan show interfaces | findstr /c:" connected" 
used as condition to check the effective connection

Comment: Done. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple IF-THEN-ELSE, isn't it?

```
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
timeout /t 300
for /l %%n in (1,0,10) do (
    netsh wlan connect ssid="xxxx" name="xxxx"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo error
    ) else (
       choice /c sna /d n /t 30 /m "Text"
       if errorlevel 3 (
           echo Choice A
           exit
       ) else if errorlevel 2 (
           echo choiche N
       ) else if errorlevel 1 (
           echo choiche S
       ) else if errorlevel 0 (
           echo Default
           exit
       )
   )
)
```

If the `netsh` command gives an errorlevel geq 1 you want to show an error, **ELSE** you want to ask the user...